# TYPO3 powermail plugin in grids for bootstrap is not showing up

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, powermail, typo3-10.x

I'm using the TYPO3 version 10 and have a problem with the plugin grids for bootstrap. The grids works with images and texts with no errors but doesn't display the powermail form.

Here's a pic of the problem
[image]

I've included before the "Main" static template.
[image]

Has anyone an idea what causes the error and how to resolve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable the option "resolveChildFlexFormData"

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1 {
    dataProcessing {
        10.default {
            options.resolveChildFlexFormData = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Thomas :)